# About passing a char[] to isdigit()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables, error-handling

I'm currently learning C and I'm trying to create a program where the program checks whether a user inputs a letter or an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char a[256];
    printf("\n Please enter a number or a letter: ");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    if (isdigit(a[256]) == 1)
    {
        printf("\n %c is a number.", a);
        printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit(a[256]));
    }
    else if (isdigit(a[256]) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n %c is a letter.", a);
        printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit(a[256]));
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the program, this is what I get:

```
Please enter a number or a letter: 15
15 is a letter.
The return value is 0.
```

Or this:

```
Please enter a number or a letter: X
X is a letter.
The return value is 0.
```

Any input I type always return the same output. I wanted to pass an array of char so that the program will take in the entire input (*e.g.* If I input "230", the program will not just check "2" but "230").

Comment: You need to review arrays. a[256] refers to a memory location outside the array. Write the code first to do it without arrays and without input (no scans), just use constants. first a = 'c' and a = '1' for example. Then try it with arrays pre-assigned array[4] = "cat" and array[4] = "123". once you have that working, add input.

Answer (score 1):

Mis-match type (save time, enable all warnings), no width limit, wrong index, wrong compare (`is...()` return values: Only 0, not 0 important.), wrong function (use `isalpha()` to test for letter), wrong range passed.  (`is...()` expect EOF,0-255, not `char`, which may be -128-127)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char a[256];
    printf("\n Please enter a number or a letter: ");
    // scanf("%s", &a);
    scanf("%255s", a);  // limit input, use matching type
    // if (isdigit(a[256]) == 1)
    if (isdigit((unsigned char) a[0]))
    {
        // printf("\n %c is a number.", a);
        printf("\n First character %c is a digit.", a[0]);
        // printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit(a[256]));
        printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit((unsigned char)a[0]));
    }
    // else if (isdigit(a[256]) == 0)
    else if (isalpha((unsigned char)a[0]))
    {
        // printf("\n %c is a letter.", a);
        printf("\n First character %c is a letter.", a[0]);
        // printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit(a[256]));
        printf("\n The return value is %d.", isdigit((unsigned char)a[0]));
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("\n Neither digit nor letter.");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program only detects the first character. He or She wanted to pass an array of char so that the program will take in the entire input (e.g. If I input "230", the program will not just check "2" but "230").

Comment: @Daniate I read the "whether a user inputs a letter or an integer" (singular) and was led to believe only 1 character was important.  I now see an implied different requirement "I wanted to pass an array of char so that the program will take in the entire input (e.g. If I input "230", the program will not just check "2" but "230")."  Made it wiki for anyone to amend.